# Post from React to Ruby (not rails)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby

I have created a Twitter clone using Ruby in the backend and React in the front end. I have managed to fetch all tweets and I am trying to post a tweet. It is connected but it is posting nothing. Literally an empty tweet.

Below is the React code.

```js
const TweetsFeed = () => {
  const [tweet, setTweet] = useState("");

  const tweetChangeHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTweet(event.target.value);
  };

const postTweet = async () => {
    const postRequest = {
      method: "POST",
      params: tweet,
    };
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:9292/tweets", postRequest).then((response) =>
      response.json().then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
    );
    fetchTweets();
  };
```

Below is the Ruby route and create method code

```rb
post '/tweets' do
  Tweet.create(tweet: params[:tweet])
end

def self.create(tweet:)
  result = DatabaseConnection.query("INSERT INTO tweets (tweet) VALUES ('#{tweet}') RETURNING id, tweet;")
  Tweet.new(
    id: result[0][0], 
    tweet: result[0][1]
  )
end
```

Below is the form

```html
<form className="new-tweet-form" action="/tweets" method="post">
  <div className="pp-input">
    <img src="./images/pp1.jpg" alt="" />
    <input
      type="text"
      name="tweet"
      placeholder="What's happening?"
      onChange={tweetChangeHandler}
    />
  </div>
  <div className="extras-button">
    <Extras />
    <Button type="button" onClick={postTweet}>
      Tweet
    </Button>
  </div>
</form>
```

It does post to the database, but an empty tweet everytime.

Comment: Try replacing `params: tweet` with `body: JSON.stringify({tweet: tweet})`. But even then you're going to create a bunch of spam tweets. You need an id in the front end and to make sure you're not making a request `onChange` as it triggers with every keystroke.

Comment: I tried that as well and itt still doesn't save it. Thanks for the tip on the id. For now all I want is to be able to save the tweet.

Comment: What happens exactly? What `params` do you receive serverside?

Comment: If I just use the plain old submit form action, then it works. But with the above, nothing happens server side.

Comment: To precise, it returns `nil`.

Comment: add type of content you are sending to the backend in headers eg: `Content-Type: application/json`.